# ios view resized in storyboard but does not show during runtime

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

i have a view with subview and tableview in it. please see picture below. i increased the height of 'CheckoutNTotal' view in storyboard and adjusted the x,y co-ordinates for 'Tbl Orders' accordingly. But when I run it in simulator, the 'CheckoutNTotal' view does not show full height. what could be going on. I have attached storyboard view, runtime view as well. Appreciate any help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT 1:

thanks for replying. did you mean 'View Debugging' under 'Debug' menu? that didn't show anything. but i do see these nasty constraints messages in console:

Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this:
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
(
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x600003a6c780 _UILayoutGuide:0x7f9269f2edd0.height == 64   (active)>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x600003a6c460 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9269f2edd0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f9269f2e4f0 )>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x600003a6c960 _UILayoutGuide:0x7f9269f2f160.height == 49   (active)>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x600003a6c7d0 _UILayoutGuide:0x7f9269f2f160.bottom == UIView:0x7f9269f2e4f0.bottom   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003a6d8b0 V:|-(84)-[UIStepper:0x7f926b550320]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f9269f2e660 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003a6da90 UILabel:0x7f9269f29c60'Tip'.centerY == UIStepper:0x7f926b550320.centerY   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003a6dbd0 V:[UILabel:0x7f9269f29c60'Tip']-(123)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f9269f2e660 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003a6e260 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9269f2edd0]-(0)-[UIView:0x7f9269f2e660]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003a6e490 V:[UIView:0x7f9269f2e660]-(342)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9269f2f160]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003a36990 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7f9269f2e4f0.height == 568   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003a6da90 UILabel:0x7f9269f29c60'Tip'.centerY == UIStepper:0x7f926b550320.centerY   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.

so i guess i need to fix them.

Comment: What does the View Debugger say?

Comment: did you mean 'View Debugging' under 'Debug' menu? that didn't show anything. but i do see these nasty constraints messages in console:

Comment: Yup, you mustn’t ever ignore those. Serious stuff.

Comment: removed all constraints and made new ones. now i don't see any layout warnings in console output but the subview is still messed up. how do i paste new screenshot?